# $\sum_{n=1}^{n=p}\left(\frac{n^2+a}{p}\right)=-1$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, jacobi-symbol

Show that if $(a,p)=1$, $p$ an odd prime then, $\sum_{n=1}^{n=p}\left(\frac{n^2+a}{p}\right)=-1$,
where $\left(\frac{n^2+a}{p}\right)$ is the Jacobi symbol.

Comment: What is $\alpha$ ?

Comment: It's $a$ and $a$ is any integer co prime to $p$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy the question has been taken from Niven Zuckerman, section 3.3 question 20. Please help me to solve it.

Comment: An introduction to theory of numbers by Ivan Niven , Zuckerman.

Comment: @nicomezi i hope this helps now.

Comment: Yes much better thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some hints to get started

- Let $N(a)=\{ \exists\,, x \in \mathbb{Z}_{p} \ : \ x^2\equiv a \pmod{p}\}$, then it is easy to see that $|N(a)|=1+\left(\frac{a}{p}\right)$
- Count the number of solutions to $x^{2}-n^2\equiv a\pmod{p}$ for a fixed $a$.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your answer. Sorry for the delayed message.

Comment: I am unable to follow what to do after what you have written.